# User memberships in applications using openam or sso

Tags: wordpress, tomcat, paypal, saml, openam

I have wordpress setup that is membership based. They pay to have a membership and they have rights based on that. I don't want to rewrite all that functionality. I want it so that if one is paid up in wordpress, they can use my OTHER web application which is a tomcat web application.

So wordpress would allow access to my other web application.

I have looked at openam and it has the userregistration functionality that I want but not the connection to paypall that I need.

For example:

- I want a users with member ship level 1 to have a one week free
  trial.
- I want a users with member ship level 2 to have a one month of
  product 1.
- I want a users with member ship level 3 to have a one
  month of product 1 and 2. I want a users with member ship level 4 to
  have a one month of product 1 and 2 and 3.
- I want a merchant
  interface where if they have not paid up, they loose their
  authentication  privilege.

This type of membership control exists for wordpress but at this moment I don't know if it can be used for my other application.

I was wondering if there is an openam, openid type product that would do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own Policy Condition plugin for OpenAM to achieve this. However make sure that J2EE agent protecting the application is running policy client mode 'self' so you have full access to the request in the policy framework

Comment: I agree, I could. I was hoping that this was prevalent enough that a module already had been created by now.